# Vue.js ternary expression vs v-show

Tags: vue.js, conditional-operator, vue-props

I have to change icon type play/pause conditionally, passing it via props.

In such case should I use the ternary expression in order to pass correct prop?

```
<my-icon :icon="!isPlaying ? 'play' : 'pause'"></my-icon>
```

Or it would be better to use v-show to achieve the best performance?

```
<my-icon v-show='!isPlaying' :icon='play'></my-icon>
<my-icon v-show='isPlaying' :icon='pause'></my-icon>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Either should be fine and the resulting performance difference should be negligible.

**Additional Thoughts:**

Performance wise, I would imagine that the difference in time to render would be negligible. As a personal preference, the usage of the first one seems more appealing to me as it only inserts one `<my-icon />` element into the DOM rather than two and hiding one.

As an alternative to `v-show`, you could use the [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) conditional directive to not even render the element that won't be displayed in the DOM for example two above. This would result in only one in the DOM at a time similar to example one. Below is the usage for `v-if`:

```
<my-icon v-if='!isPlaying' :icon='play'></my-icon>
<my-icon v-if='isPlaying' :icon='pause'></my-icon>
```

While this is probably slightly more performant than `v-show` since the second non-displaying element doesn't have to be added to the DOM, the difference again is probably negligible.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be removing the v-if and sending the different values to `icon` prop using computed

```
<my-icon :icon="getIcon"></my-icon>
```

```
export default {
 computed: {
  getIcon() {
   return isPlaying?'pause':'play':
  }
 }
}
```

Through the above method, you can send any values based on the different conditions with having one short line of code in the `template` section

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your welcome buddy